# Publish app in playstore

Tags: android, google-play

I published my app last day on playstore. But I didn't find it on playstore. And when I tried following solution to find that.

```
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=yourpackagename
```

I got a blank page with the message "We're sorry, the requested URL was not found on this server.". What is the problem?

On playstore app published option is ticked. Status of the app in Alpha.

Comment: What is value of yourpackagename? it should the package name of your application.

Comment: in the playstore search box.. enter your developer name and you may find it.. give it a shot

Comment: Are you sure you published to production? Your app may be published as in BETA (or Alfa).

Comment: What is your app name or the Organization name

Comment: @SerjLotutovici yes it is in alpha what to do now?

Comment: @Balu I need to promote my app to prod?

Answer (score 3):

An App published for alpha-test will only be visible for the users that are in your alpha-testers list. As those have to be Google Groups or Google+ Communities you cannot see the App in the Play Store, not even when you have the exact link to the App.

**Solutions:**

1) Publish the App to production. After a few hours it should be downloadable in the Play Store not only for you but for everyone.

2) Create a Google Group in which only you (and maybe some friends who can test your App as well) are member and add this Google Group to your alpha-testers list (to find at: Developer Console->[Your App]->APK->Alpha-Test).

Comment: Added to this, you also have to send an invitation to every tester who's already on the Google Group. Invitation link is in Developer Console->[Your App]->APK->Alpha-Test->Manage list of testers

Answer (score 2):

1. Make sure your app status is **not** under "**Submitting update**" state.
2. https://play.google.com/apps/**testing**/yourpackagename should work.
3. **If closed alpha**: 
   Also under playstore app, the account which you have added in your alpha testers list should be selected. Then tap on above URL by replacing package name and you should see the "Become a tester" page. Agree and download the app from playstore.

If in **Open Alpha** mode then simply tap on the above url, it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Check from your device,If not seen you might have not published it your publish account.Also AFAIK It will take some time to get published.Gud luck.

Answer (score 0):

You should just wait about 24-48 hours, and it will show up. 
Reason for this i think its that the app before publishing needs to get into their database, server, get trough lot of testing... 
On mine dev console it said that app is published and i had same problem"we are sorry for... ". 
Waited and after two days it showed up...

Comment: This should be a comment.